# Python how to add words from text file that contains letters from another word

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains words between 2-7 letters. Now I want to to do the following:

1. Make a new sub-list with all words with 7 letters.
2. For each 7 letter word **W**, list all the words from the original list that are anagrams of any subset of letters of **W** (including itself). Each such list should be ordered from shortest to longest.
3. Save the output from step 2 into a new file.

***For example:***

**Original list in input file**

```
peaty
meant
eat
payment
motion
emotion
no
novel
inlet
violet
violent
```

**What I want:**

The seven letter words in the list are *payment*, *emotion* & *violent*.

**Expected output file**

```
eat|peaty|meant|payment 
no|motion|emotion
no|novel|inlet|violet|violent
```

---

I have started to create a new list with only the 7 letter words:

```py
with open('list1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('newlist.txt', 'w') as f2:
   for line in f1:
       if len(line) <9:
            f2.write(line)
```

But now I don't know how to continue.

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you have 2 lines for `no`? Are duplicated letter important?

Comment: It is not homework. I just need the 7 letter words to the right. And then all words that is possible with the letters from this word to the left.

Comment: And in my example. You can create 'no ' with the letters from 'emotion' and 'violent'

Comment: What should happen with "toilet" here? Contained in "violent' or not?

Comment: And what if you had `tea`? Should it be a subset of `eat`? (same question with anagrams of 7 letter words)

Comment: It should only use the words in the list.

Comment: @Mat the question is about generalization, how do you want to handle words with duplicated letters and anagrams?

Comment: I just want to use the letters once. And anagrams should also be included.

Comment: So should `toilet` be present in the list, would it be a subset of `violent`?

Comment: @kelly from the example output, *inlet* is in the list of words for *violent* which has letters out of order, which means it's not important.

Comment: @MatKoffman ***Side note:*** When dealing with files, it's recommended to use the PathLib libraries instead of old style `open('list1.txt', 'r') as f1`. Here's some motivation -
https://builtin.com/software-engineering-perspectives/python-pathlib

Comment: @sprite I'm of course asking because of the double t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note. I am assuming here the duplicated letters matter. `abb` is not a subset of `abc`. If this is not the case, you can replace `Counter` by `set`.*

##### Using 7 letters words as reference

I would first split the list in two (7 letters and others), then use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to compare the composition of pairs generated by [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

lst = ['peaty', 'meant', 'eat', 'payment', 'motion', 'emotion',
       'no', 'novel', 'inlet', 'violet', 'violent']


# split input list in two
words7, others = [], []
for w in lst:
    (others, words7)[len(w)==7].append((w, Counter(w)))

# for all combinations of 7 letter words and others
# if a subset, add to dictionary
d = {}
for (w1, c1), (w2, c2) in product(words7, others):
    if c2 < c1:
        d.setdefault(w1, []).append(w2)
```

Output `d`:

```
{'payment': ['peaty', 'meant', 'eat'],
 'emotion': ['motion', 'no'],
 'violent': ['no', 'novel', 'inlet', 'violet']}
```

Variant to handle anagrams:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

lst = ['peaty', 'meant', 'eat', 'payment', 'motion', 'emotion',
       'no', 'novel', 'inlet', 'violet', 'violent', 'aligned', 'leading']

words7, others = [], []
for w in lst:
    (others, words7)[len(w)==7].append((w, Counter(w)))

d = {}
for (w1, c1), (w2, c2) in product(words7, words7+others):
    if c2 <= c1 and w1 != w2:
        d.setdefault(w1, []).append(w2)
```

Output `d`:

```
{'payment': ['peaty', 'meant', 'eat'],
 'emotion': ['motion', 'no'],
 'violent': ['no', 'novel', 'inlet', 'violet'],
 'aligned': ['leading'],
 'leading': ['aligned']}
```

##### General case

If you want a more generic approach to compare all words to words of a shorter length, sort the values by increasing lengths and use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

lst = ['peaty', 'meant', 'eat', 'payment', 'motion', 'emotion',
       'no', 'novel', 'inlet', 'violet', 'violent']

cnts = [(x, Counter(x)) for x in sorted(lst, key=len)]

d = {}
for (w1, c1), (w2, c2) in combinations(cnts, 2):
    if c1 <= c2:
        d.setdefault(w2, []).append(w1)
```

Output `d`:

```
{'novel': ['no'],
 'motion': ['no'],
 'emotion': ['no', 'motion'],
 'violent': ['no', 'novel', 'inlet', 'violet'],
 'peaty': ['eat'],
 'meant': ['eat'],
 'payment': ['eat', 'peaty', 'meant']}
```

*Note that this approach only generates one of the combinations of anagrams. If you need both you can add `d.setdefault(w1, []).append(w2)` if `c1 == c2`.*

```
d = {}
for (w1, c1), (w2, c2) in combinations(cnts, 2):
    if c1 < c2:
        d.setdefault(w2, []).append(w1)
    elif c1 == c2:
        d.setdefault(w2, []).append(w1)
        d.setdefault(w1, []).append(w2)
```

##### from a file, to a file

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

with open('list1.txt', 'r') as f1:
    lst = f1.read().splitlines()

words7, others = [], []
for w in lst:
    (others, words7)[len(w)==7].append((w, Counter(w)))

d = {}
for (w1, c1), (w2, c2) in product(words7, words7+others):
   if c2 <= c1 and w1 != w2:
        d.setdefault(w1, []).append(w2)
            
with open('newlist.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for k,l in d.items():
        f2.write(f'{"|".join(l)}|{k}\n')
```

Output:

```
peaty|meant|eat|payment
motion|no|emotion
no|novel|inlet|violet|violent
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying to get this work with my text file. It is just words in a list like the original list. But I cant get it work. Do you have any tips how to solve it?

Comment: @Mat just cover the file to list, then the dictionary to strings. I updated the answer with an example